# King Arthur and knights at the round table puzzle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, induction

Can you help me with this math problem :

Each of the $K$ knights from the round table needs to choose a card which is marked with a number from $1$ to $N$, $N \ge K$. The cards all have a different number.

King Arthur will cancel the conquest if the knights choose the cards in a way that the product of the number that the knight has (marked with $A$), and the number of the knight to the left of him (marked with $B$), subtracted by $1$, is divisible by $N$. Is it possible for the conquest to be cancelled?

Mathematically written, is it possible that $~~~N|A(B - 1)~~$ ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is King Authur a knight?  Do they all choose different cards?

Comment: How about $A=1$, $B=2$? (with at least two knights)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to resolve $$\exists C \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots, N\} ~~\bigg( N~\mid~ C_1\prod_{c \in C} c \bigg)$$

Comment: Does it have to be true for every knight around the table ?

Answer (score 0):

What if one of the Knights draws the $N$ card?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I believe this does answer the question, as well as I can guess the meaning of the question.

Comment: DanielV: Anyhow, we prefer longer answers with development. So you should substantiate your answer with argumentsd and proofs!